# How to access an object Foo contained in a scala package object from Java?

Tags: java, scala

How to access an object `Foo` contained in a scala package object from Java?

```
package object domain { object Foo }  domain$.MODULE$.Foo$.MODULE$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this has changed as of Scala 2.8.1, but the proposed `domain$Foo$.MODULE$` doesn't work. You have to use `domain.package$Foo$.MODULE$`.

And it's a little different for objects, methods, etc. Given the scala class:

```
package object domain {
  object foo
  def bar = 42
  val baz = 1.0
}
```

You can access `foo`, `bar` and `baz` in Java like:

```
domain.package$foo$.MODULE$
domain.package$.MODULE$.bar()
domain.package$.MODULE$.baz()
```

While I was trying to figure this out, I thought we were in trouble because Scala generates a class named `package`, which of course you can't import in Java. Fortunately, we only need the `package$` companion object, which you can import.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at an object in an object in the Scala lib, e.g. `scala.math.Ordering.Boolean`, you can get it from Java using `scala.math.Ordering$Boolean$.MODULE$`. I see no reason why package objects shouldn't behave like normal objects in this regard, so your `Foo` instance should be `domain$Foo$.MODULE$`